# how to stop create view if already created django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-generic-views

please help me in making this application in django project

Here is models.py file code

```
from django.db import models
from bio.models import Profile

class Question(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField(max_length=500)

   def __str__(self):
     return self.name

class Answer(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='question', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  text = models.TextField(max_length=400)
  created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return "{0} on {1}".format(self.question, self.profile)
  
  class Meta:
    db_table = 'answer'
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['profile', 'text', 'question'], name='unique answer')
    ]
```

here is views.py file code

```
class DetailViewMixin(object):
  details_model = None
  context_detail_object_name = None

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DetailViewMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context[self.context_detail_object_name] = self.get_detail_object()
    return context

  def get_detail_object(self):
    return self.details_model._default_manager.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])


class AnswerCreate(DetailViewMixin, CreateView):
  details_model = Question
  context_detail_object_name = 'question'
  model = Answer
  form_class = NewAnswerForm
  template_name = "qna/answer.html"
  success_url = reverse_lazy('qna:list')

  def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.profile_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    form.instance.question_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

here is my forms.py code

```
from django import forms
from .models import Answer

class NewAnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Answer
    fields = ['text',]

  def clean(self):
    try:
        Answer.objects.get(text=self.cleaned_data['text'].lower())
        raise forms.ValidationError('Answer exists!')
    except Answer.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return self.cleaned_data
```

where am I going wrong????

I want that if user answers one question then he couldn't answer it again

how can i do form validation if object is already created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a UniqueConstraint to Answer so no combination of Question and Profile can be repeated:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint